# laravel return Use of undefined constant PASSWORD_ARGON2ID

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use Argon2id in place of bcrypt to hash password. I'm using PHP 7.2.33 and Laravel 7.28.  Can you please help me to enable argon2id.
currently, I just tried with the below code

```
return password_hash('password', PASSWORD_ARGON2ID);
```

Can you please help me. Thank you

Comment: Use PASSWORD_ARGON2I instead of PASSWORD_ARGON2ID because its available in php 7.3

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

> PASSWORD_ARGON2I - Use the Argon2i hashing algorithm to create the
> hash. **This algorithm is only available if PHP has been compiled with
> Argon2 suppor**t.

You have to compile php with Argon2 to be able to use it.

Here is a tutorial:

https://framework.zend.com/blog/2017-08-17-php72-argon2-hash-password.html

Answer (score 0):

You use

```
return password_hash('password', PASSWORD_ARGON2I);
```

instead of

```
return password_hash('password', PASSWORD_ARGON2ID);
```

Because, `PASSWORD_ARGON2ID` constant is supported for PHP version >= 7.3.

In the case you want to use `PASSWORD_ARGON2ID`, you have to upgrade your PHP version.